# There is website Service for unavailable domains?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, redirects, 404, parking

I have few domains, I don't want to use it on my website and I want to redirect different server, says site not available. 
I would be happy if I can set different message for every domain.

Comment: "I want to redirect different server" - what do you mean? If you want to redirect to a different server then it's not a problem; is it? If you want to set up a simple holding page and don't have proper hosting (to redirect to) then your domain registrar _might_ offer this service.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy has a service for parked domains, I'm sure other registrars have similar services too, but basically it's just a simple single page website, perhaps with some contact information so you could sell your domain... you can make one webpage for all your parked domains and redirect all of them to this page.

Redirecting shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: I tried to use godaddy parked domain service but they keep changing back DNS records. strange behavior...
I don't want to take a hosting and build a simple html webpage.
I would prefer for service I can use for this.
And maybe setup custom message for every domain.

Comment: Uhm.. then contact the GoDaddy, they have a great support team and they should be able to help you.

Comment: Sure I can use godaddy support and Fix it.
But I think of using different service and use less godaddy services.